# Working with float values in MASM and getting them into variables

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point, masm, x87

I am trying to get the value from ST(0) register and get it stored in the variable. But my attempts are failing horribly.
Here is part of code, where I am interacting with the float values. The correct result is stored in the ST(0) register, but how do I get it out of it in a variable? With this current code, I get the value -

```
8256657931607403600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Which is better than nothing, but pretty horrible too, because it needed to be 1.5 xD

```
    fldz
    fild [FirstEndSum]
    fild [SecondEndSum]
    
    fdivp st(1),st
    fstp [FirstRoot]
    
    push offset FirstRoot      ; 1.5 from ST(0)
    push offset FormatString   ; From Data: FormatString    db      "%f",0
    call printf
    pop eax
```

Comment: You are passing a pointer to your value, instead of the value itself.  The `double` value itself is what needs to go on the stack, not the address of a place where it is stored.

Comment: Try instead `sub esp, 8` and `fstp qword ptr [esp]`.

Comment: What compiler is this for, and what calling conventions?  I don't understand the `pop eax` at the end.

Comment: It is the masm32sdk compiler. ``` pop eax ``` is because printf is cdecl calling convention, which requires cleaning of the stack. 
And trying your solution - Now I get ``` 0.000000 ```
Screenshot from debugger - https://prnt.sc/ut0dnw

Comment: But you pushed 8 bytes onto the stack (and should have pushed 12), so don't you need to remove the same number?

Comment: Why do you have `push [esp+8]` after the `fstp` in the code you linked?  I don't think that should be there.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh thanks :D Appereantly, just saving the value to the [ebp+8] was enough. But why it works without pushing to the stack?
In cdecl it is supposed to push arguments backwards? Format string is being pushed first and value is the second. But it works xD

Comment: Think about what `push` does: it decrements `esp` and then stores the value at the address to which `esp` points.  So `sub esp, 8` and  `fstp [esp]` has exactly the effect of "pushing" the `double` onto the stack.  And then you will push the `FormatString` pointer after that because yes, the cdecl convention pushes right to left.  I'm not sure it's completely correct yet because the `double` may need to be aligned to an 8-byte boundary; maybe someone else can clarify this.